# CUDA C best practices: unsigned vs signed optimization

Tags: c, cuda

In the [CUDA C Best Practices Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html) there is a small section about using signed and unsigned integers.

> In the C language standard, unsigned integer overflow semantics are well defined, whereas signed integer overflow causes undefined results. Therefore, the compiler can optimize more aggressively with signed arithmetic than it can with unsigned arithmetic. This is of particular note with loop counters: since it is common for loop counters to have values that are always positive, it may be tempting to declare the counters as unsigned. For slightly better performance, however, they should instead be declared as signed.
>
> For example, consider the following code:
>
> ```
>     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
>          out[i] = in[offset + stride*i];  
>     }
> ```
>
> Here, the sub-expression `stride*i` could overflow a 32-bit integer, so if i is declared as unsigned, the overflow semantics prevent the compiler from using some optimizations that might otherwise have applied, such as strength reduction. If instead i is declared as signed, where the overflow semantics are undefined, the compiler has more leeway to use these optimizations.

The first two sentences in particular confuse me. If the semantics of unsigned values are well defined and signed values can produce undefined results, how is it the compiler can produce better code for the latter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The text shows this example:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
     out[i] = in[offset + stride*i];  
}
```

It also mentions "strength reduction". The compiler is allowed to replace this with the following "pseudo-optimised-C" code:

```
tmp = offset;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
     out[i] = in[tmp];
     tmp += stride;
}
```

Now, imagine a processor that only supports floating point numbers (and integers as a subset). `tmp` would be of type "very large number".

Now, the C standard says that computations involving unsigned operands can never overflow, but instead are reduced modulo the largest value + 1. That means that in the case of unsigned `i` the compiler has to do this:

```
tmp = offset;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
     out[i] = in[tmp];
     tmp += stride;
     if (tmp > UINT_MAX)
     {
         tmp -= UINT_MAX + 1;
     }
}
```

But in the case of signed integer the compiler can do whatever it wants. It doesn't need to check for overflow - if it does overflow then it's the developer's problem (it could cause an exception, or produce erroneous values). So the code can be faster.

Comment: The compiler would have to check for overflow _before_ performing the addition, otherwise it would be incurring in _undefined behavior_

Comment: @K-ballo the scenario is imaginary anyway... my assumption is that `tmp` is some "very large number" (e.g. long double), so it can check it after the addition. But it's only a strange example, of course it depends on the actual processor.

Comment: Why not just let the unsigned ints wrap around and blame the programmer, just as it does with the signed ints?

Comment: @BarryBrown the unsigned will wrap around according to the standard. The point it that signed integers are not even guaranteed to "wrap around" - the program is allowed to crash on signed overflow. The difference is that the standard says what to do in one case, and leaves the other case as "undefined behaviour".

Answer (score 2):

Its because the definition of C limits what the compiler writer can do in the case of the unsigned integers. There is more leeway to fool around with what happens when signed integers overflow. The compiler writers have more room to move, so to speak.

That's the way I read it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the semantics of `signed` and `unsigned` becomes relevant for performance on processors which don't support all the word sizes defined by C. For instance, say you have a CPU that only supports 32-bit operations and has 32-bit registers, and you write a C function that uses both `int` (32-bit) and `char` (8-bit*):

```
int test(char a) {
  char b = a * 100;
  return b;
}
```

Since the CPU can only store `char` in 32-bit registers and can only perform arithmetic on 32-bit values, it will use a 32-bit register to hold b, and a 32-bit multiplication operation.

Because the C standard states that signed integer overflow causes undefined results, it is fine for the compiler to create code for the above function that returns a value that is higher than 127 when `a` is higher than 2.

However, if unsigned values are used:

```
unsigned int test(unsigned char a) {
  unsigned char b = a * 100;
  return b;
}
```

The C standard defines the overflow semantics for unsigned operations, so, the compiler will have to add a masking operation to ensure that the function does not return values higher than 255 even when `a` is higher than 2.

---

* The C specification allows `char` to wider than 8 bits, but that would break many programs, so we assume a compiler that uses 8-bit values for `char` in this example.